# GCMRegistrar.unregister not working

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Hi i want to unregister from GCM, i have used below code, but i am still getting notification

i have used below code on LOGOUT button click

```
      GCMRegistrar.unregister(getApplicationContext());
```

on **GCMBaseIntentService** also i am getting notification

```
     @Override
protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
    System.out.println("It's unregisterd");
}
```

can anyone solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the new `GoogleCloudMessaging` class, you don't need to use the `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER` intent. Simply use

```
GoogleCloudMessaging.unregister().

public void unregister ()
```

This unregisters the application. Calling `unregister()` stops any messages from the server. This is a blocking call—you shouldn't call it from the UI thread. You should rarely (if ever) need to call this method. Not only is it expensive in terms of resources, but it invalidates your registration ID, which should never change unnecessarily. A better approach is to simply have your server stop sending messages. Only use unregister if you want your application to stop using GCM permanently, or you have a compelling reason to recycle your registration ID. Throws IOException if we can't connect to server to unregister.